# In Ruby, exception thrown when concatenating exception with String

Tags: ruby, exception

I executed below code in ruby.

**code:**

```
def doCalc
    begin
        print( "Enter a number: " )
        aNum = gets().chomp()
        result = 100 / aNum.to_i
    rescue Exception => e       
        result = 0
        puts( "Error: " + e + "\nPlease try again." )
        retry   # retry on exception
    else
        msg = "Result = #{result}"
    ensure
        msg = "You entered '#{aNum}'. " + msg
    end
    return msg
end


puts( doCalc )
```

Getting Error:

> retry.rb:15:in `+': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)
>           from retry.rb:15:in`ensure in doCalc'
>           from retry.rb:15:in `doCalc'
>           from retry.rb:21:in`'

I entered 0 on console because I wanted to check how this error handling code works. Basically wanted to check working of ***retry***. I understood how retry works but this error confuses me as it says 'e' which has been assigned exception is nil which cann't be the case as if I change line#15 as:

```
puts e
```

then no error comes. In fact it prints:

> divided by 0

I am experienced java but new in ruby. What am I missing here?

Comment: You sure it's not this part `msg = "You entered '#{aNum}'. " + msg` since `msg` may be nil here? Especially since you stack trace clearly references the issue being the ensure block.

Comment: As a final note puts will try and call to_s on the Object so in this case you should add `e.to_s` as part of your String assembly

Comment: Your error message makes no sense. There aren't even 21 lines in your code, so how could it possibly refer to line 21? It's obvious that the error message you posted and the code you posted don't belong together. Unfortunately, there is nothing we can do to help you, if we don't know what the code and the error message are.

Comment: However, my best guess is that the error is on line 13, where you essentially assign `msg` to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since when you gave `0` as input, There was exception of `divide by 0`. Execution went to `rescue` block and later to `ensure` block, leave `msg` to `nil` type,

What you should had done is something like below,

```
def doCalc
    begin
        print( "Enter a number: " )
        aNum = gets().chomp()
        result = 100 / aNum.to_i
    rescue Exception => e
        result = 0
        msg = "Error: #{e.message}"
        puts("#{msg} \n Please try again." )
        retry   # retry on exception
    else
        msg = "Result = #{result}"
    ensure
        msg = "You entered '#{aNum}'. #{msg}"
    end
    return msg
end


puts( doCalc )
```

Comment: @nanosoft was this helpful?